# Pandas dataframe merging with duplicate columns but with preference to one?

Tags: python, pandas, merge, stock

I have two time series of stock price in pandas, I am trying to update an older version of a dataframe with a newer sample of data which overlaps in some rows,

```
            open time        open        high         low       close            volume              close time
0 2021-12-29 23:45:00  1.33200000  1.33800000  1.32300000  1.33200000  2180554.80000000 2021-12-29 23:59:59.999
1 2021-12-30 00:00:00  1.33300000  1.33500000  1.30600000  1.31500000  4271266.40000000 2021-12-30 00:14:59.999
2 2021-12-30 00:15:00  1.31600000  1.32700000  1.30100000  1.32100000  4728804.80000000 2021-12-30 00:29:59.999
3 2021-12-30 00:30:00  1.32200000  1.33500000  1.32100000  1.32700000  3267302.30000000 2021-12-30 00:44:59.999
4 2021-12-30 00:45:00  1.32800000  1.33200000  1.32100000  1.32500000  1518480.80000000 2021-12-30 00:59:59.999
5 2021-12-30 01:00:00  1.32500000  1.32600000  1.31300000  1.32300000  1504166.70000000 2021-12-30 01:14:59.999
            open time        open        high         low       close            volume              close time
0 2021-12-30 00:45:00  1.32800000  1.33200000  1.32100000  1.32500000  1518480.80000000 2021-12-30 00:59:59.999
1 2021-12-30 01:00:00  1.32500000  1.32600000  1.31300000  1.32300000  1504166.70000000 2021-12-30 01:14:59.999
2 2021-12-30 01:15:00  1.32300000  1.32500000  1.31600000  1.31800000   887868.00000000 2021-12-30 01:29:59.999
3 2021-12-30 01:30:00  1.31700000  1.32200000  1.30900000  1.32200000  1287084.10000000 2021-12-30 01:44:59.999
```

I have tried to outer merge but it is of little help, as it just fills with nans the duplicate columns,

```
ndf = pd.merge_ordered(df,df1,on="open time")

            open time      open_x      high_x       low_x     close_x          volume_x            close time_x      open_y      high_y       low_y     close_y          volume_y            close time_y
0 2021-12-29 23:45:00  1.33200000  1.33800000  1.32300000  1.33200000  2180554.80000000 2021-12-29 23:59:59.999         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN               NaN                     NaT
1 2021-12-30 00:00:00  1.33300000  1.33500000  1.30600000  1.31500000  4271266.40000000 2021-12-30 00:14:59.999         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN               NaN                     NaT
2 2021-12-30 00:15:00  1.31600000  1.32700000  1.30100000  1.32100000  4728804.80000000 2021-12-30 00:29:59.999         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN               NaN                     NaT
3 2021-12-30 00:30:00  1.32200000  1.33500000  1.32100000  1.32700000  3267302.30000000 2021-12-30 00:44:59.999         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN               NaN                     NaT
4 2021-12-30 00:45:00  1.32800000  1.33200000  1.32100000  1.32500000  1518480.80000000 2021-12-30 00:59:59.999  1.32800000  1.33200000  1.32100000  1.32500000  1518480.80000000 2021-12-30 00:59:59.999
5 2021-12-30 01:00:00  1.32500000  1.32600000  1.31300000  1.32300000  1504166.70000000 2021-12-30 01:14:59.999  1.32500000  1.32600000  1.31300000  1.32300000  1504166.70000000 2021-12-30 01:14:59.999
6 2021-12-30 01:15:00         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN               NaN                     NaT  1.32300000  1.32500000  1.31600000  1.31800000   887868.00000000 2021-12-30 01:29:59.999
7 2021-12-30 01:30:00         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN               NaN                     NaT  1.31700000  1.32200000  1.30900000  1.32200000  1287084.10000000 2021-12-30 01:44:59.999
```

How can I perform the merge in which the values from df1 are preferred, so the resulting dataframe does not have duplicates?

Comment: `df.set_index('open time').combine_first(df1.set_index('open time')).reset_index()`?

Comment: @Emma Works great, Thank you!

Comment: @Emma Why is the intermediate set_index() required?

Comment: Because `combine_first` looks for the same index value to overwrite.   In your case, you want to overwrite value upon the same `open time`.